# Forbidden access to folders

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm getting below error when I'm trying to access a folder in Linux CENT OS server.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /blog/ on this server.

Apache Server at www.franchisedirectory.com.au Port 80
```

I changed settings in httpd.conf and .htaccess but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there somewhere I can change this?

Comment: Do you have read and write permission to /blog ?

Comment: 777 is set for all files and sub-directories including blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You don't have access to `/foo` ..." doesn't mean the **path** `/foo` in the OS. It means you don't have access to the **URL** `/foo`.  For instance, suppose that requests for that domain go to a docroot at `/var/www/webroot`. Then `/foo` (unless you aliased it elsewhere) goes to `/var/www/webroot/foo`. That is the directory that needs the proper permissions (in addition to `<Directory>`/`.htaccess` controls.)

I just set up the following on my server to prove this:

```
Alias /foo /bar
```

I created a `/bar` directory at the shell prompt. I removed all permissions with `chmod a-rwx /bar`. Then I restarted Apache and surfed for `/foo`. Guess what?

```
You don't have permission to access /foo on this server.
```

It clearly reports the URL, not the path it is translated to.

I do not recommend `chmod 777` by the way, because that means world writable. `chmod 744` is better: writable to owner, readable to others. If it's a directory, `755` (add the execute bit too).

Good luck, mate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to solve this you should type:

`chmod 777 /blog`

Probably you it doesn't have write permission on that folder so it will give you that forbidden error.